# How to best join/merge two pandas dataframes on a column(pandas.core.series.Series and pandas.core.frame.DataFrame)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.5, series

I am trying to join/merge two dataframes (`df_apply` and `df_result`) based on a common column (`name`). Sounds simple enough, but one of the dataframes has column types `pandas.core.series.Series` and the other one has column types `pandas.core.frame.Dataframe`. This causes the *merge* (`pd.merge(df_apply, df_result, on='name')` to result in an error:

`ValueError: The column label 'name' is not unique.
For a multi-index, the label must be a tuple with elements corresponding to each level.`

After dropping the indexes of both tables I was able to *join* (`df_apply.join(df_result)`) the tables, but this results in a dataframe with weird column names, which are inaccessible in any way - the column names become (sbt,)     (gra,)  (pot,)  (oni,)  (wwh,)  (class_max,)    (prob_max,)     (tf_time,)  (name,)     (processing_time,).

I've tried converting the `pandas.core.series.Series` to a `pandas.core.frame.Dataframe` like so:

- `df_apply.name = df_apply.name.rename(None).to_frame()`
- `df_apply.name = df_apply.name.to_frame()`

but in the end the result of `type(df_apply.name)` is always: `pandas.core.series.Series` and the result of `type(df_result.name)` is always `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`.

The two dataframes (a single row of each) look like this:

**df_result:**
[image: df_apply]

**df_apply:**
[image: df_result]
I expect to be able to easily join these tables based on the name, but this pesky pandas column type structures are making it very hard. How does one go about it?

**UPDATE:**

I solved the issue by exporting the `df_result` to csv and importing it back again. At this point both columns have column types of `pandas.core.series.Series` . I hope this helps, but still doesn't answer my question of how to join such tables without doing this...?

Comment: Whow is created `df_apply` ?

Comment: `df_apply` is a subset of a larger table (`df`) and is created via d `df.query` (`df_apply = df.query("name not in @df_training.files")`) . Concerning the second question - I do `.reset_index(drop = True)` to both tables and it doesn't change the outcome. Do you mean to try it only on `df_result`.

Comment: It seems some data related issue, are data confidental?

Comment: I updated the question to post my half-assed solution - saving to csv and importing it anew. Don't know if this is the programatic/pythonic way of doing it, but worked...

Comment: hmmm, what is `print (df.columns)` ? there is no MultiIndex?

Comment: Yes, you are right, there is a multiIndex. But I thought that if I do `.reset_index(drop = True)` this will not be an issue? Pardon my foolishness, but do you mind an explanation as to how to work around this?

Comment: No, there is no foolish, but ugly bug. I have idea - how working `df_apply.columns = df_apply.columns.get_level_values(0)` or maybe `df_apply.columns = df_apply.columns.get_level_values(1)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that when `df[colvar]` results in `core.series.Series`,
it can be changed to a data frame by referencing it with additional brackets:
`df[[covar]]`.